# CSS table is resizing on some browsers

Tags: css, resize, width, css-tables

I have a table with four columns. First and third column must have a width of 132px. If you see the page on Explorer, both columns respect the width specified. But on Firefox and Chrome, the columns grow up to 206px, and I don't want this happend.

**Columns**

[image: Styles of Columns]

**Table**

[image: Style of table]

I have set the table with table-layout: fixed. And I have specified width, min-width and max-width to 132px for these td, but browsers continue doing as they please.

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

**Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/65o82kv0](http://jsfiddle.net/65o82kv0)**

CSS for columns

```
.cabecera {
    width: 132px;
    color: white;
    max-width: 132px;
    min-width: 132px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #82005E;
}
```

CSS for table(s)

```
#bloqueVehiculo table,
#bloqueTren table,
#bloqueIncidencia table,
#bloqueMantenimiento table,
#bloqueClasificacion table,
#bloqueEstado table,
#selectorVehiculo table {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 23px auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Image of table on Explorer
[image]

Image of table on Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Show a snippet!

Comment: Add jsfiddle or post html/css if possible.

Comment: If you have table-layout:fixed, all you need to do is specify the width of each table cell explicitly. With the total width of the table being 95%, and two of the cells being 132px, the other two cells need to be 47.5% - 132px wide. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/m7e08c6z/1/ works the same way in all browsers.

Comment: Hi dear friends!!! This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65o82kv0/ 

If you expand the result view, you can see how the four tds are resizing. Only second and fourth td should make it

Comment: And size of first and thirdth td is not the specified

Answer (score 0):

1. Not every browser has equivalence in terms of CSS, the way they interpret stylesheets.
2. You can specify a container of a fixed size and keep the table as its child element to make the size same across browsers.
3. Please check for any in-line CSS, because they can sometimes override the external CSS file you could have.